# File exists but not found at runtime c#

Tags: c#, file-io

Hello there my code is like that:

```
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
         Process myProcess = new Process();
         // Launch the usb backup creator
         myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         // get path of recovery drive
         myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = (Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\RecoveryDrive.exe"); ;
         myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
         myProcess.Start();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,ex.Source);
     }
}
```

The file exists in system32 directory, but the exception thrown says that the file does not exist?
Is that related to UAC privileges?

Comment: have you checked your path? try inserting a line before the filename: string path=(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\RecoveryDrive.exe"); and check if your path is correct

Comment: the breackpoint reports that the path is correct 100/100

Comment: My guess - you're running as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS and the same file doesn't exist in `SysWow64` (the location that the file system redirector substitutes for `System32`)

Comment: if you run the process normally there is no problem, programmatically there is a problem.

Comment: @madoui20032003 Try by running as Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're experiencing the effects of the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because you're running as a 32-bit process (compiled for 32-bit or for AnyCPU with "Prefer 32-bit") then you probably want to use the following code:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows),
             "sysnative",
             "RecoveryDrive.exe");
```

to get the correct path. You can determine if this is the case by checking the [`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

References:

- [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)